# How to protect my Exe file which written in c#.net?

Tags: source-code

I created one software which written in c#.net and when i created setup file .exe file will be the output but in this .exe file is ex tractable by some software and easy to access the codes.How to prevent this?

Comment: Although this answer was marked as a duplicate w.r.t. DRM, I think this answer may assist you:  Look at SLP, formerly from Microsoft

http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1091/396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what you do, no matter what you use, somebody will be able to extract/infer the source code of your application from the binary. There's just no way around it. In the worst case they can run the application through a debugger and with assembly knowledge it could be possible to infer the source code.

Having that said, there *are* many good obfuscatory for .Net. They make it a bit more difficult to extract the source code from the binary. [Here's a list of some of them on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET).

Comment: Funny I don't see SLP on that list... http://www.inishtech.com/

Comment: @makerofthings7 No disrespect, but this is Wikipedia. If there's something missing or you see something you can improve, then add it yourself instead of complaining about it.

Comment: None taken.  Also I'm not complaining... The omission makes me question market awareness whenever I would be required to make a product listing, especially when it's a former MSFT product.  Maybe there is something unpopular/undesirable with the product I don't know of.  That is where I was phishing for information ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could run your project through an obsfucator tool like [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net).

This should make it a lot more difficult to recover the original source code given the .NET binary file. Of course, this is not 100% foolproof. With enough time and effort, an attacker would probably have a high chance of deobsfucating the binary file.

Comment: its minimum requirement is .NET 4.0 but i am using .NET 3.5

Comment: @SureshE Search around for other obsfucator tools. There are plenty available out there.